# Purposely re-asking (duplicating) an old question

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette

I am trying to solve a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419221/how-to-know-if-a-user-has-opened-a-new-internet-explorer-window-or-tab-from-the).  A nearly identical question was asked in 2009.  The answer at that time was "It can't be done".  But three years later is that still the case?  I don't know.

So, I sort of re-posted the question (see above link), but with a slightly different slant (no Javascript in answer please).  But not different enough to keep it from being considered a duplicate.

My other option would be to post a bounty on the old question.  But should I really have to do that?  I mean, is that what one needs to do to get up to date info?  Spend rep?  (I actually don't care much about my rep, but I could easily have to spend all my paltry 500 points just trying to get up to date answers.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good question. My opinion would be: create a new question only if you *know* things have changed.

If you have made some research, and have *reasonable* doubts that the situation have changed (e.g. something was impossible 3 years ago, but became possible because of new software or other reasons), then I believe it's ok to ask again. You *must*, however, include your reaserch attempts and your reasons for asking it again, simply because people need to know that it's not exactly a duplicate, but a similar question with new conditions.

A bounty is rather a tool to atract attention to a question that has not yet recieved a solution. In your case, it's a different story. The solution was found 3 years ago, and it was "that can't be done".

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I did do research, but to be honest, I don't know for sure that things have changed.  What I do know is that 3 years is an eternity in IT, and whenever I give an answer based on information that is three years old, I always say "But it's probably changed since then".

Comment: This is my comment.  it might be hard to know whether things have changed.  In this case is there a protocol to follow?